# what is the difference between [1-9][0-9]* and [1-9][0-9]+ in laravel while passing id through Route

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm new to laravel and while watching video of routing in laravel I came across the above thing but it was not clear from the video that what is the difference between that + and *. Even there was no difference in results.

Comment: It's a regular expression, and `*` means none, one or many of the preceding group, while `+` means one or many of the preceding group... basically, `[1-9][0-9]*` means any number `>= 1` while `[1-9][0-9]+` means any number `>= 10`

Comment: @MarkBaker Make that an answer. There's nothing more to say ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and `*` means none, one or many of the preceding group, while `+` means one or many of the preceding group... basically, `[1-9][0-9]*` means any number `>= 1` while `[1-9][0-9]+` means any number `>= 10`

```
[1-9] - Must be one of the digits 1-9
[0-9]* - followed by none, one or more additional digits
```

and

```
[1-9] - Must be one of the digits 1-9
[0-9]+ - that must be followed by one or more additional digits
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for additional information about the `*` and `+` repetition operators in regular expressions

Comment: Hello @MarkBaker Thanks but still my doubt is not clear. you said that [1-9][0-9]* means any number >= 1 while [1-9][0-9]+ means any number >= 10. So if I use [1-9][0-9]+ then I wont be able to pass the values <=10, Right?

Comment: That's correct yes: for `[1-9][0-9]+`, the lowest possible first digit is `1` from the group `[1-9]`, and there __must__ (`+`) be at least one additional digit from the range `0-9` (`[0-9]+`), so lowest possible value is `1` followed by a `0` (`10`)

Comment: Oh okay @MarkBaker I got it now, my doubt is now all clear, Thanks a lot :-)